# Elegant way to prevent stop event firing immediately after start

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, callback

I'm writing a jQuery plugin where the events which start/stop the plugin are customisable, so potentially the same event could both start and stop the plugin (e.g. click to start and click to stop).

What's an elegant way, ideally not involving timeouts or unbinding and rebinding of listeners (and not too many "isPlaying" "isBeingStarted" flags etc..) to make sure the correct callback is called

Comment: I don't quite get the question - are you saying you want to stop people double clicking an element, which would cause your plugin to start, then immediately stop?

Comment: When the config is set so that a click will start the plugin and a click (i.e. a second click) will stop it, I don't want the stop handler to run right after the start handler on the first click

Comment: simplest way without knowing more or seeing any code is purely to have a boolean var which is set to true when the plugin starts. then if the event happens again you can test against this and you will know to stop rather than start again. but you should really post some code or say what you've tried already and why it didn't work if you expect a good answer

Comment: This doesn't work as 1) the start handler fires and sets playing = true 3) the stop handler fires and, seeing "playing = true" it runs in full, stopping the plugin. (And if I attach the stop handler first there's a similar but inverse problem). The difficulty I'm facing is that both handlers can be attached to the same event but I only want one of them to run. I can't attach 1 handler which branches as they might need to be attached to different events depending on user config.

Comment: then I think you should put up some code - you're unlikely to get the right answer with so little detail. good luck anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventual solution I've gone for is to do a quick uniqueness test for events used for stopping and starting and if there are any events used for both stopping and starting then a different listener (which does an isPlaying check) is attached to these. There's a small performance hit on loading the plugin, but after that the event handling code is about as efficient as can be.

```
function processEvents() {
    var tempStart = opts.startEvent.split(" ").sort(),
        tempStop = opts.stopEvent.split(" ").sort();
    startEventLoop: for(var i=0, il = tempStart.length;i<il;i++) {
        for(var j=0, jl = tempStop.length;j<jl;j++) {
            if(tempStart[i] == tempStop[j]) {
                stopStartEvents.push(tempStart[i])
                tempStop.splice(j,1);
                continue startEventLoop;
            }
        }
        startEvents.push(tempStart[i])
    }
    startEvents = startEvents.join(" ");
    stopEvents = tempStop.join(" ");
    stopStartEvents = stopStartEvents.join(" ");
}

    $this.on(stopEvents, function() {
        $this.trigger("stop.flickBook");
    }).on(startEvents, function() {
        $this.trigger("start.flickBook");
    }).on(stopStartEvents, function() {
        playing ? $this.trigger("stop.flickBook") : $this.trigger("start.flickBook");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

(**Note:** When I posted this answer, the question had a typo in it which made it seem like binding/unbinding would be okay as long as timeouts weren't involved.)

I don't see any need for timeouts, just bind/unbind as appropriate:

```
this.bind(startEvent, start);

function start() {
    $(this).unbind(startEvent).bind(stopEvent, stop);
}

function stop() {
    $(this).unbind(stopEvent).bind(startEvent, start);
}
```

In the above, I assume that `startEvent` is the configured start event name (and I'd probably add a namespace to it, e.g. the user passes in `"click"` but you add `".niftyplugin"` to it resulting in `startEvent` containing `"click.niftyplugin"` so you can bind/unbind at will), and `stopEvent` is the configured stop event name (with namespace).

Here's a full example, with namespaces and using `data` to remember the options (you could use a closure if you prefer) - [live copy](http://jsbin.com/uzujey):

```
// Plugin stuff
(function($) {
  $.fn.niftyPlugin = niftyPlugin;
  function niftyPlugin(options) {
    var data;

    data = {
      startEvent: (options && options.startEvent || "click") + ".niftyplugin",
      stopEvent: (options && options.stopEvent || "click") + ".niftyplugin"
    };

    this.data("niftyPlugin", data).bind(data.startEvent, start);

    return this;
  }

  function start() {
    var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data("niftyPlugin");
    $this.unbind(data.startEvent).bind(data.stopEvent, stop);
    display("Start");
  }

  function stop() {
    var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data("niftyPlugin");
    $this.unbind(data.stopEvent).bind(data.startEvent, start);
    display("Stop");
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
})(jQuery);

// Use
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    $("<p>Non-plugin hook fired</p>").appendTo(document.body);
  }).niftyPlugin({
    startEvent: "click"
  });
});
```

---

The only other alternative I see is [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) - [live example](http://jsbin.com/iwozic):

```
// Plugin stuff
(function($) {
  $.fn.niftyPlugin = niftyPlugin;
  function niftyPlugin(options) {
    var startEvent, stopEvent, running = false;

    startEvent = (options && options.startEvent || "click") + ".niftyplugin";
    stopEvent = (options && options.stopEvent || "click") + ".niftyplugin";

    this.bind(startEvent, start).bind(stopEvent, stop);

    return this;

    function start(event) {
      if (running) {
        return;
      }
      running = true;
      display("Start");
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }

    function stop(event) {
      if (!running) {
        return;
      }
      running = false;
      display("Stop");
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  }

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
})(jQuery);

// Use
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#theButton").click(function() {
    $("<p>Non-plugin hook fired</p>").appendTo(document.body);
  }).niftyPlugin({
    startEvent: "click"
  });
});
```

I don't like it, though, because it interferes with other handlers for the event. For instance, in the above, if I change the use to this:

```
// Use
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#theButton").niftyPlugin({
    startEvent: "click"
  }).click(function() {
    $("<p>Non-plugin hook fired</p>").appendTo(document.body);
  });
});
```

...so the plug-in grabs the events before the non-plug-in code, **boom**, the non-plug-in code never sees the event ([example](http://jsbin.com/iwozic/2)).

So despite the overhead, I suspect bind/unbind are your friends here.

Comment: Oops - a typo in the question. I meant "without timeouts OR unbinding and rebinding". I can't help thinking there should be a way to avoid having to undergo the rather expensive operation of unbinding/rebinding, especially when in most cases it's unecessary as the events for stop/start will normally be different (eg mouseover & mouseout)

Comment: @wheresrhys: What makes you think binding/unbinding is expensive? Unless one of the events is `mouseover` or something that potentially fires hundreds of times in a second, the bind/unbind shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The second 2 approaches don't work because of the explanation I gave in a comment on the question (in fact what you've written is pretty much identical to what I have already, and it's really annoying it doesn't work)

Comment: @wheresrhys: Yeah, sorry, you must have been reading it as I was removing it. :-) The bind/unbind works a treat, though. Tried it in Chrome, Firefox, and IE7.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll have to go for that method, although to answer your earlier question, on the grand scale of things, bind and unbind aren't gonna be a big performance bottleneck (although, particularly when using namespaces, there are a lot of internal jQuery methods called and a few regex executions), but if I'm making an open source plugin that could be used in a variety of different scenarios by different people I try and keep it as lightweight as possible.

Comment: @wheresrhys: And that's a good thing to do. :-) The only other thing I can think of is `stopImmediatePropagation` and I've added an example to the answer, but I can't say I like the effect on non-plug-in code.

Comment: Hmmm, but I'm using the original click event to fire a custom event "stop.myPlugin" so your approach may work for me and be immune to interfering with other event handlers. I'll try it out

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill, but an elegant way to not have to maintain a bunch of flags (e.g. "isPlaying") is to use a [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Here's a jQuery implementation: https://github.com/DukeLeNoir/jquery-machine